# texi2dvi error when compiling tex files using RStudio and knitr since Mac OSX 10.10 upgrade

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, tex

I am having an issue compiling Latex files using RStudio (0.98.1079) and Knitr (1.7) and R (3.1.1). The issue has only started since I upgraded to the latest version of Mac OS X.

I am basically unable to compile any Tex files from RStudio, including the minimal files. Running the `knit2pdf` function produces a .tex file but does not produce a PDF file. Instead it returns the following error:

```
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Test.tex' failed.
```

The weird thing is that I can compile the .tex file using another Tex program (i.e. Texpad/TexShop) just fine. Just for reference, I am using TexLive 2013 and trying to compile using pdfLateX.

**Update**: I have just uninstalled and upgraded all of the software involved in this problem (R, RStudio, Knitr, and LaTeX). However, I am still having the same issue. My gut says that the `tex2dvi` function does not point to the correct LaTeX installation on my computer but I have no idea on how to diagnose / fix the issue (strangely, I can also not run `pdftk` using the `system` command in R).

**Issue Resolved**: This issue was resolved through a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491934/running-system-command-from-r-console-cannot-locate-installed-programs-since-upg/26492588#26492588). It turns out that Yosemite does not allow programs to forward the `PATH` variable to child processes... The (temporary) solution is to launch RStudio through the Terminal.

Comment: Do you mind if we close this question since it is essentially identical to the related post you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: No not at all! I wasn't sure whether to close it or not.