# Running system command from R console cannot locate installed programs since upgrading to Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I have been having [some weird issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477679/texi2dvi-error-when-compiling-tex-files-using-rstudio-and-knitr-since-mac-osx-10) with R (3.1.1) and RStudio (0.98.1079) and I suspect that it is due to the fact that these programs are not longer referencing the right places after I upgraded to Mac OSX 10.10.

In particular, I cannot seem to find packages that I know I have installed on my computer to run using the `system` command in the R console. That is, running `man pdflatex` in a Terminal window yields the help manual for PDFLATEX. However running `system('man pdflatex')` from the R console yields the error message `No manual entry for pdflatex.`

The issue persists even though I reinstalled R, RStudio and MacTex since I upgraded to Mac OSX 10.10. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yosemite has a bug wherein some environment variables, including `PATH`, appear twice in a program's environment with different values. For instance, you might notice that `Sys.getenv("PATH")` will show you one PATH, and `system("echo $PATH")` will show you an entirely different one.

I expect that most of your problems are due to this bug.

There are a few workarounds you can try immediately:

1. You can manually forward `PATH` yourself. Try this:

   ```
   > system2("man", "pdflatex", env=paste0("PATH=", Sys.getenv("PATH")))
   ```
2. Or, you can start RStudio from Terminal:

   ```
   $ open /Applications/RStudio.app
   ```

Both the R and RStudio engineers have implemented workarounds in the last few days. R (as of 3.1.2) and RStudio (as of 0.98.1087) should behave as you'd expect.

Comment: So the first solution does not work for me... However, the second solution does. Thank you so much!

Comment: `open -a rstudio` is somewhat simpler, and most probably does the same (cannot try, don't have 10.10).

Comment: Just an update for folks who are hitting this: we now fully understand the issue and we'll have a fix in RStudio soon.

Comment: @JoeCheng Is this considered fully resolved? I'm still having the ```texi2dvi``` error when using a task scheduler to run a .Rnw file:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731493/texi2dvi-error-when-running-a-rnw-script-with-launchcontrol

Answer (score 0):

*There are a host of questions about similar problems. All of them appear to come up when you update OS X to either Yosemite or Sierra with an older version of R already installed.*

The easiest solution is to [completely uninstall R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390548/how-to-uninstall-r-completely-from-os-x) (note the comments about using `which R` !), and then to install it again.

This also solves problems such as R showing different version numbers in terminal and the GUI.