# RStudio can not use git in Yosemite

Tags: r, git, rstudio

After upgrading my Mac to Yosemite, I am not able to use `git` in RStudio anymore.
(I can still use `source tree` or `git` independently from RStudio)

Not sure whether it is related to the PATH issue posted here:
[Running system command from R console cannot locate installed programs since upgrading to Mac OSX 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491934/running-system-command-from-r-console-cannot-locate-installed-programs-since-upg)

I tried the above solution, but did not work.

In RStudio, I specified the path to Git in `Tools/Global Options.../"Git/SVN"` correctly (as I used before)
But, in in `Tools/Project Options.../"Git/SVN":Version control system` the only option left is `(None)`.

RStudio: 0.98.1074 (updated to 0.98.1083, still does not work)

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             darwin10.8.0
>   system         x86_64, darwin10.8.0
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          1.0
>   year           2014
>   month          04
>   day            10
>   svn rev        65387
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
>   nickname       Spring Dance

Comment: See this blog post: http://www.compmath.com/blog/2014/10/r-and-rstudio-incompatibility-with-yosemite-mac-os-x-10-10/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it is essentially the same as the solution found from my link in the post. It did not work.

Comment: Did you look at the comments and the newest version of Rstudio?

Comment: Where is your `git` installed? This is likely a `PATH` issue.

Comment: What does `Sys.which("git")` return?

Comment: to hrbrmstr: it returns "/usr/bin/git", which is the same as where git is installed (and was working before my upgrade to Yosemite). And it is also the same as where I specify in RStudio: Tools/Global Options.

Comment: to Tyler: I did. Otherwise I would not think that it is a PATH issue as I pointed out in my question. Also, as pointed out in the post, I am using the latest version of RStudio that is published yesterday.

Comment: to Kevin, it is installed at "/usr/bin/git". I did think it is a PATH issue by reading the post and comments from the link I posted in my question. But I tried both solutions provided from that link, but did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. When you enter the directory you used to use with git in your terminal (`cd path/to/directory`) type `git status`. In my case I received the message:

`Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.`

Apparently, I had to agree to the Xcode licence. When you re-run the line with sudo (`sudo git status`) and enter your password in the terminal you get the whole license displayed. Now you only need to type `agree` and everything is done. Re-start RStudio and the git functionality is back again.

Best wishes,
Marco

Comment: Thanks, this one works. It is indeed not a path issue as in many other cases.